# AWS Root volume Encryption

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, encryption, amazon-ebs, aws-cli

In my scenario, I have some old  EBS volumes that are not encrypted. To satisfy new corporate security measures, all data needs to be encrypted so I need to compile a plan to encrypt the unencrypted in the least disruptive way (Ideally with no downtime)?

Can anyone suggest What is the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 6):

Here are the steps to encrypt EBS volume:

- Create IAM KMS encryption key
- Create snapshot of the root volume
- Copy a snapshot which enables the encrypting option
- Create a new Encrypted volume from an encrypted snapshot
- Detach the existing volume and replace it with the Encrypted volume

For more information you can read [this article](https://medium.com/tensult/encryption-of-ebs-root-volumes-41e9627eb85f).

Comment: just to understand, Click on the unencrypted snapshot, pull down to copy, and click the encrypt button to encrypt the copy. stop the instance & Detach the existing volume and replace it with the Encrypted volume right?

Comment: @samtech2021, yes, from snapshot you can create encrypted volume.

Comment: Just to be pedantic, is there any procedure to perform it with no downtime (Unencrypt EBS volumes to be Encrypted)?
What is the advice for more than 100 of EBS volumes to perform the task?

Comment: @samtech2021, AFAIK no. I do this research some time ago (was on similar situation). But if your machines are behind a loadbalancer you can create new EC2 with encrypted disk, start it, attache to LB, then deattach old one.

Comment: Just wanted to know, Is there any guides/documentation available for the ALB attached instances volumes?

Comment: IMHO ALB are services, managed by Amazon and you do not have access to volumes there

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135291/discussion-between-samtech-2021-and-romeo-ninov).

Comment: There does not appear to be a way to do this without downtime.

For more than 100 EBS volumes, you could script the process because every step can be performed using the APIs.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done but it is convoluted. Root volumes can be replaced on a running instance using a snapshot or an image. If you  create a snapshot from a newly encrypted volume, however, it will result in an error. But, you can make an image from that snapshot and then the root volume can be replaced without stopping the instance. Here are the steps:

1. Create a snapshot of the unencrypted volume
2. Create a volume from the snapshot and add the encryption key. IMPORTANT: root device name must be the same. ie: /dev/xvda
3. Create a new snapshot from the encrypted volume
4. Create an image from the encrypted snapshot
5. Replace root volume with new image: Actions > Monitor and troubleshoot > Replace root volume

One thing to note is that you can't change encryption keys with this method, only add one. To change it, the instance must be stopped.

Some useful tips:

- keep track of ids
- use tags and descriptions to keep track.
- make sure snapshots and volumes have finished and are available.
- make sure new image has same settings as the original instance.

More info here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/replace-root.html